# Domain Controller Communication Timeout Limit

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller, windows-server-2019

**THE DOMAIN**

I have a domain setup with a parent/child schema. All servers are Microsoft Windows 2019 Standard. There are 2 top level DCs and the 2 child domains each have their own 2 DCs. The issue I am having happens maybe once a month when we do testing. We have encryption software on the computer whereas we forget to set the autologon flag during patching some times and the computer stops pre OS boot to wait for a PIN to be put in to get past encryption. When this happens it effects use of domain management on the top level.

**THE PROBLEM**

If a DC on the child domain is stuck on that pre OS boot, and I try to open Active Directory Users & Computers on the top level domain controller, the `mmc.exe` will launch but the window will not show up for almost 10 minutes. This slow down is in direct connection when the child domain controllers are not online and maybe stuck at that Pre-OS screen. When AD opens it is really slow especially when expanding sections of AD and it lags as long as it did when waiting to open.

**THE QUESTION**

Is there a way to shorten this, what I assume is a, time out time? Or some way to speed this up so we can actually get work done in the event we might lose a DC or have network issues between locations?

Comment: If there are two domain controllers, the clients should use remaining available DC. You should perform a capture on a client to confirm the client is doing this, and what the response is from the domain controller.

Comment: @GregAskew This is not a client issue. Its one DC to the other DCs. If I am trying to access AD on a top level DC, it lags hard if one is disconnected for whatever reason.

Comment: I'm not saying it is a client issue, but the capture on the client would be helpful information to pursue the issue. Also correlated with a capture on the local DC that is up.

Comment: @GregAskew I am a little confused. Can you explain what you are looking for in the capture?